# How is procfs created?

Tags: linux, filesystems, kernel

After looking at the `proc` directory, the size is about 140.7TB

[image: directory properties]

What is the /proc mapped to, how are the files present in it created?

> The proc file system is a pseudo-file system which is used as an interface to kernel data structures.

I get that it acts as an interface between the kernel and userspace but I don't quite understand how a pseudo-file system works, and why it's so huge in size. Is the /proc directory recreated by the kernel every boot? How exactly is the `/proc` directory generated; is there a implementation of that I can view?

Answer (score 2):

Read carefully [proc(5)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man5/proc.5.html).

`/proc/` is a *pseudo* ["*virtual*" file system](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Virtual_file_system) containing *pseudo* files and directories. These do not consume any resources on the disk (and not much in kernel memory - the kernel needs a tiny amount of memory to serve `/proc/` independent of the apparent size of files in it.). They are just a convenient interface between the kernel and the user applications. **So `/proc/` gives a** (virtual) ***view* of what is happening inside your system.** In particular, the `ps` command is accessing extensively `/proc/` since `/proc/1234/` gives a lot of information about the process of pid 1234.

<sup>In the late 1980s, `/proc/` did not exist -e.g. on SunOS3; and programs like `ps` reporting status of the running system had to read physical kernel memory (e.g. thru `/dev/mem`). This was insecure and inconvenient (you had to recompile `ps` when the kernel changed).</sup>

Several files in `/proc/` have an apparent size of 0, but are sequentially readable. `/proc/self/maps` is a good example. Try the `cat /proc/self/maps` then the `ls -l /proc/$$/fd/` commands in a terminal. Other files are apparently huge because their size convey some significant information. `/proc/kcore` is a significant example. It "*represents* the physical memory of the system" but of course it does not eat all the RAM!

**The kernel does not exactly *create* files in `/proc/`;** it just gives to applications the *illusion* of seeing files there. In fact, the kernel is synthetizing data for every I/O operation (e.g. [syscalls](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/System_call) like [read(2)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/read.2.html) etc...) done by user applications. Hence, practically speaking, most files in `/proc/` (in particular `/proc/self/maps` or `/proc/interrupts`  etc...) are behaving more like pipes than like files (so their size, as given by [stat(2)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/stat.2.html), is 0 but you can read several lines - practically a few hundred bytes - from them).

BTW, with [FUSE](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Filesystem_in_Userspace) filesystems, you could even write a server application which also gives the *illusions* of files in your *pseudo* file-system.

Practically speaking, the 140 Terabytes of contents in your `/proc/` does not mean much. It is that big because some `stat` syscalls report some *fictious* size, with a grand total of 140Tb.

Comment: So these files are present in the memory? That still doesn't explain the size being 140.7tb

Comment: So, the kernel re creates this pseudo filesystem at every boot? If its stored in memory every configuration should be wiped at shutdown right?

Answer (score 1):

Some of the configuration tools of the Linux NET-2 and NET-3 release rely on the /proc filesystem for communicating with the kernel. This interface permits access to kernel runtime information through a filesystem-like mechanism. When mounted, you can list its files like any other filesystem, or display their contents. Typical items include the loadavg file, which contains the system load average, and meminfo, which shows current core memory and swap usage.

To this, the networking code adds the net directory. It contains a number of files that show things like the kernel ARP tables, the state of TCP connections, and the routing tables. Most network administration tools get their information from these files.

The proc filesystem (or procfs, as it is also known) is usually mounted on /proc at system boot time. The best method is to add the following line to /etc/fstab :

procfs mount point:

```
none        /proc       proc    defaults
```

Then execute **mount /proc** from your **/etc/rc** script.

The procfs is now configured into most kernels by default. If the procfs is not in your kernel, you will get a message such as: mount: fs type procfs not supported by kernel. You will then have to recompile the kernel and answer “yes” when asked for procfs support.

Reference from : http://www.tldp.org/LDP/nag2/x-087-2-iface.procfs.html